# Winforms DataGridView Row Autosize during edit?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

When editing and adding new lines in a DataGridView's cell/row the row itself is only resized after finishing the edit & leaving the cell. Is there any way to autosize/grow the currently edited rows so that the full (& new) content remains visible?

Answer (score 0):

I have found for small amounts of data, letting the user edit in the datagridview is fine but when it comes to more than a 'one-liner' then I find it better to give the user a textbox instead that gets populated on cellClick and saved on a 'save' button click or textbox.leave event.